# Create a type containing only non-shared properties from two interfaces

Tags: typescript

Given two interfaces:

```
type I1 = {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: number
}

type I2 = {
    a: string
    b: string
    d: string
}
```

I need to create a type which only has properties which are not shared by the two interfaces.

```
type Result = XOR<I1, I2>

// should become
type Result = {
    c: number
    d: string
}
```

I tried this:

```
type XOR<T1, T2> = {
    [K in keyof (T1 & T2)]: T1[K & keyof T1] | T2[K & keyof T2]
    // ^^ I need something like "not in" here
}
```

But I am not sure how to only map over keys which are not in both `T1` and `T2`.

[I prepared this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgRhgXhgb2DLMCGAuGAZxACcBLAOwHNNsAjA4862rAYwIoFcBbOqEsAC+wUJFhwATCnStcjUpRrYYDIopYqAJguY0RY6DAAaAeQBKAHgAqCADQxrkgHwy0MOQG0A0jEowAaygwAHsAMxgAClsYADJHSQBKAF0CWx84wODwxwRkmAAfBIz4oNCIp3y5AHpqmAA9evgYCigoLSIQnigQAAslGAAbMiCYACIKEJA-CjGYXoEoYVFDWHMoQi5B6dQzK0QHKWdRWphwI3XN7bdgU5UOFt5+QTvsHXU9W7qhIA)

Comment: This isn't XOR and more like NAND tbh (unless we're talking about set theory?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type XOR<A, B> = {
    [K in Exclude<keyof A | keyof B, keyof A & keyof B>]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : K extends keyof B ? B[K] : never;
};
```

Exclude keyof A ∩ keyof B from keyof A ∪ keyof B to get the keys that are only in either A or B. Then just get the right value from A or B for the key.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgjFAvFA3gWAFBW1AhgLigGdgAnASwDsBzTHKAI0JIprpwGNDKBXAWwYRSmAL6ZMoSLABMSVO2wFiZKrSw4my1mvoATZirYYxGCeGgANAPIAlADwBBADRQAQgD456ddgDaAaSgqKABRAA8OABseXQg7AGsIEAB7ADMoBygAHyhElPTXFzy0jKgAMlykko8AXUJAiDDgCEpdIkr80oB+DICaqHqoRubW9uKCqB7XPoGoSggANyEAblFV0wxJaAAVOWt7eBcYaXdloA)

---

Oh, I haven't had my afternoon coffee yet...

```
type XOR<A, B> = Omit<A & B, keyof A & keyof B>;
```